# A way to extend the UV grid in the UV Editor

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Instead of having empty space outside UV space, continue the grid. Drawing the grid over images may also be useful

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm looking for "A way to extend the UV grid in the UV Editor" :)